# How to type a tab (indent) in comments in PowerShell ISE?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

This is weird.

I know tab is for command completion in the PowerShell ISE and fine so. But, it also messes up the editing pane.

Do this:

1. File > New (`Untitled1.ps1` opens)
2. Press tab (all fine, you get an indent)
3. type enter, `#` (comment) and press tab after it
   expected: one would get indentation after the hash
   actual: one gets the hash replaced by `$PSVersionTable` or whatever the command prompt has in its history! (tab and Shift-tab circle through those)

Does this mean no-one uses tabs within comments in PowerShell scripts, or that no-one uses comments in PowerShell scripts?

Can I turn off this behavior anywhere?

Also, the behavior seems to be inconsistent. If I e.g. type `##`, sometimes tab does not do the completion (it does not enter a tab either).

Can others reproduce this?

[image: screenshot]

System:
Windows 8.1 Pro
PowerShell ISE

Comment: I can reproduce this. And the TAB completion is even working in the comments!

Comment: But only if I type a blank after the #

Comment: Thanks. So is it a bug..? I have no idea why anyone would want that. PowerShell is very annoying to get started, anyways. This is simply one more little rock more in the boot.

Comment: I consider it a bug. And I think they have forgotten that auto-complete is not needed in this context. Another funny thing is the TAB's behaviour. It isn't context-aware and just brings (On my PC) the User profile's subfolders!

Comment: You can always copy/paste that from notepad. Imagine you are typing a serious comment and need a TAB :D

Comment: @Alireza I don't think it's a bug. As mentioned in my answer, I find it useful behavior.

Comment: It shouldn't matter anyway as PSISE replaces the tab with 4 spaces (or just enough spaces to reach the nearest `Column%4 -eq 0` or multiple of 4). If you need a tab, use spaces. Or enter the tab first, then add the #. Or paste the Tab as has been suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer the main question, you can enter <kbd>Alt+09</kbd> (using numeric keypad) to enter `<Tab>`.

For the behavior described, I see this as expected behavior. You can get history completion by typing `#` and part of a previous command then pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> repeatedly will cycle backwards through matching history. Typing `#` alone will match all history starting with the last command.

```
 Does this mean no-one uses tabs within comments in PowerShell scripts?
```

Anecdotal, but I've never used tabs in a single line comment, but I do often use tabs within multiline comments which are bracketed by `<#` and `#>`. E.g.

```
<#
Functions
    Get-Foo
    Get-Bar

Variables
    $Foo
    $Bar
#>

Function Get-Foo { ...
```

With multiline comments, the auto-completion will not be an issue.

```
, or that no-one uses comments in PowerShell scripts?
```

I don't know why this would be implied by the behavior; I always use a single space to start a line comment.

I find this helpful when developing a script as I often try expressions in the command pane if I'm unsure of the behavior, then add the expression to the script if it works.

So, my workflow would be:

1. <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> to go to the Command Pane
2. Type a command
3. If the command did what I wanted, <kbd>Ctrl-I</kbd> to go to the Script Pane
4. Type `#<Tab>`, and the line is added to the script.

Comment: Thanks, great comment that sheds light to how it works the way it does. Also, I had not learned the syntax for multi-line comments, yet. Makes sense, in a bizarre way.

Comment: When there is no autocomplete candidate, TAB still doesnt work as TAB inside inline comments or block comments. Seems to behave correctly outside of the comments..

Comment: TIL the #TAB trick.  Also, tabs work in my ISE in block comments just list outside comments.